# Checkout form not getting saved

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce site with Django. So I'm at this point where, users can add items to their cart, proceed to checkout but for some reason, my checkout form is not being saved.

I made sure that I have registered my models, and ran migrations, but every time I fill out my form and go to check in my admin panel, it says: 0 user addresses. What is the problem?

My views.py:

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    address_form = UserAddressForm(request.POST or None)
    if address_form.is_valid():
        new_address = address_form.save(commit= False)
        new_address.user = request.user
        new_address.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        raise Http404
    context = {"address_form": address_form}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Place Order"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
from orders import views as orders_views
path('checkout/', orders_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
```

Comment: Does `address_form.is_valid()` return True? Please check.

Comment: Not entirely related to your question, but you should always do a redirect after a form submission. In other words, you should have a `redirect(...)` within your `if` block.

Comment: Okay I am adding them(edit)

Comment: Yea now it says Http4040

Comment: But why is my form not valid?

Comment: print form.errors

Comment: It says: Not Found: /checkout/

Comment: Looks like you need to go back to basics. Learn about forms here: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/. There's an example of a complete view that uses a form near the end of the article.

Comment: Essentially this can be marked as a duplicate of your next question: [Django checkout not accessible: Page not found (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339977/django-checkout-not-accessible-page-not-found-404). In truth that one was a wilful duplicate of this one, but I am reversing the duplicate linkage, as that one has an accepted answer.

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `login_required` decorator is not a function to be called. So, remove the parentheses first, then try to re-run your code. Also, the `request.user` is an object, not a string or any other variable data type. So, if you want your user's username you should write `request.user.username`.

Furthermore, try to add two different function views or one class-based view, to handle separately the **GET** and the **POST** request. The **GET** request will render the form to the user and will render the template. The **POST** request will redirect the user back to the homepage if the form submitted successfully. Last but not least, remember that a **POST** request does not have query parameters. So, you cannot use `?redirect=checkout` in your URL.

### Update

If you do not want URL consolidation, then your urls.py file should be something like this:

```
from [project_name].orders import views as orders_views

url_patterns = [
    path('checkout/', orders_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
]
```

Reference: https://www.webforefront.com/django/consolidatedjangourls.html

Comment: But my form.errors is still saying : Not Found: /checkout/

Comment: Try to post your `views.py` file, because if it cannot find a URL that is probably due to an error in the `views.py` or `urls.py` file.

Comment: I have posted my views.py file

Comment: I have also posted my urls.py @georgekrax

Comment: I cannot even render my checkout form and this form is not invoked from AJAX

Comment: Did it solve your problem?