# Django checkout not accessible: Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-urls

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce site with Django. So I'm at this point where, users can add items to their cart, but when I try to proceed to checkout, for some reason, my checkout form is not displayed rather, it says:

> Page not found (404)

I made sure that I have registered my models, and ran migrations.

What is the problem?

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    address_form = UserAddressForm(request.POST or None)
    if address_form.is_valid():
        new_address = address_form.save(commit= False)
        new_address.user = request.user
        new_address.save()
    else:
        raise Http404
        print(form.errors)
    context = {"address_form": address_form}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Place Order"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
from orders import views as orders_views
path('checkout/', orders_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
```

Comment: So your form is successfully rendered however is not valid or you cannot even render it? It's not clear from your question. And please clarify whether this form is invoked from AJAX or not.

Comment: I cannot even render it

Comment: And this form is not invoked from AJAX

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've implemented `GET` request handling incorrectly, for reference see [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) from the docs. In your case form was always invalid because in case of `GET` request it was initialized with none. However you don't even have to validate empty form on GET request.

Your code updated:

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if address_form.is_valid():
            new_address = address_form.save(commit= False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            return # TODO : return what?
    else:
        # otherwise (if GET request) we get here
        address_form = UserAddressForm()

    context = {"address_form": address_form}
    return render(request, "orders/checkout.html", context)
```

And you need to specify what is supposed to happen when the form is valid: redirect for example.